# Open file in Macro file with file explorer, run macro in user file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get it so I have a Excel File with a Button that opens up a file explorer so the user can select the excel file of their choice. Once they select that file, I want my macros in the blank button file to run in that file that the user provided with data.

Another option could be is to run through that process but have the macros run in the macro file and then automatically export a new file once the macros have run? Kind of banging my head on what would be the best way to do this and how to write it.

```
Sub browseFilePath()
On Error GoTo err
Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'To allow or disable to multi select
fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False

With fileExplorer
    If .Show = -1 Then 'Any file is selected
        [filePath] = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    Else ' else dialog is cancelled
        MsgBox "You have cancelled the dialogue"
        [filePath] = "" ' when cancelled set blank as file path.
    End If
End With
err:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I have this so far that is only just browsing for a file via button.

Comment: So where exactly is the issue here? Open the file with the [Workbooks.Open method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) and perform what ever you want in that file. We need a more precise question here I think. • Note that `…GoTo err` will exit your sub without showing a message in case of an error. That means you will never notice if something goes wrong in your procedure (it's more like *"good luck running this procedure, if it fails … shht … don't tell anyone"*). So you should `MsgBox` before `Exit Sub` in case of an error.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and notes @Peh . the issue is I want the macro to run in the blank excel file and then create a copy after the macro has run

Comment: So the button is in that blank file? Can you be more precise please? Which file has the date and which macro do you want to run where?